# unsubscribe on Firebase onAuthStateChange does not work

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use Unsubscribe() but it does not work.

```
var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
unsubscribe()
readCourses(user.uid) //1 function
addElement(user) // 2 function   
})
```

The first function reads data from database so the idea is to show it only once, thats why I want to stop the reading of the user info. Second function writes data on the database so it updates information. I try to stop the onAuthStateChange with unsubscribe() but when I use function 2 to get user info thats why it is inside the onAuthStateChange function, it runs again first function and duplicates the info from the database because function 1 runs again. How can I run this just once?? unsubscribe does not stop it!! Thanks I am new.I already checked. But it does now work for me.

```
var espacioforCards=document.getElementById('espacioCards')// Div 
var nombreCurso;
var descripcionCurso;
var obtenerNombreCurso=document.getElementById('obtener nombre 
curso')//button

function lecturaCursos(uid){
console.log('leyendo...datos')

var cursos = dbRef.ref("Usuarios").child(uid).child("cursos")
  
  cursos.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()){
        
         //spinner
          document.getElementById("spinner").style.visibility = 
     "visible";
          //console.log(snapshot.val());
          snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
 
 
 
crearTarjeta(childSnapshot.val().nombre,childSnapshot.val().descripcion)
            
          })
          
          document.getElementById("spinner").style.visibility = 
     "hidden";   
      }else{
          console.log('No hay datos')
          document.getElementById("spinner").style.visibility = 
 "hidden";   
      }     
    }); 
}

function crearCurso(userRef,nombreCurso,descripcionCurso){    

userRef.child(
    'cursos').update({[nombreCurso]:{'nombre': nombreCurso, 
'descripcion': descripcionCurso}})
 }

 function crearTarjeta(nombreCurso,descripcionCurso){
 let card = document.createElement("div")

 card.setAttribute("class","card")
 card.setAttribute('style', 'width: 15rem; margin:5px')
 card.setAttribute("id", nombreCurso);
 card.innerHTML+='<img src="img/nuevosm.jpg"class="card-img-top" 
 alt="..."></img>'

 let cardbody = document.createElement("div")    
 cardbody.innerHTML+= '<h5 class="card-title">'+nombreCurso+'</h5>'
 cardbody.innerHTML+= '<p class="card-text">'+descripcionCurso+'</p>'  
 cardbody.innerHTML+='<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">al curso</a>'

 card.appendChild(cardbody)
 espacioforCards.appendChild(card) 

 }
  function addElement (user) {    
 console.log('adding elements...........')    
 obtenerNombreCurso.addEventListener("click", function(){
  
  nombreCurso=document.getElementById('nombre del curso').value
   descripcionCurso=document.getElementById('descripcion del 
   curso').value
   if(Boolean(nombreCurso) && Boolean(descripcionCurso)){      
          
    crearTarjeta(nombreCurso,descripcionCurso)
    let  userRef=dbRef.ref('Usuarios').child(user.uid)
     
    crearCurso(userRef,nombreCurso,descripcionCurso)
    //location.reload(true)
   }else{
    console.log('you must fill in')        
   }
  })
 }
```

Comment: I was not able to replicate this issue just by the code provided. Can you please edit and add code for other 2 functions so we can check the issue?

Comment: sure! thats a lot but there you go